# Hibernate Delete all data from Table using Named Parameters

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to delete all data in table using namedParameters in Hibernate.
My HQL look like this (actually I am getting name of the Entity using java reflection but for simplicity consider this code):

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery("delete :table");
query.setParameter("table", "MyEntity");
query.executeUpdate();
```

I am getting an error unexpected token near line [delete :table]

I suppose I am getting this error because namedParameters must be bind to some value ?
(id = :tableId). Is it possible to delete table using namedParameters in hibernate or is there any alternative how to makes this works ?

Thanks

Comment: No. But you can use `"delete from " + entityName`.

Comment: Is it ok to use query like this ? I mean you are using string concat. It's not considered as a good practice is it ?

Comment: Well, you need to make sure the entity name comes from a trusted location. Not from a user input, for example. But you don't really have a choice: a query parameter can't be part of the structure of the query: the database needs that structure to prepare the execution plan of the query.